# How to make function or loop for making label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a python newbie.
Now I am practicing to make simple calculator in `tkinter` platform.

Then, within my code especially in making label, it looks repetitive.
Is there a way to implement function or loop to make the script simpler and nicer?

Here is my attempt:

[image]

your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you post your code in SO instead of taking a screenshot.

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

Since each label has its own text, using loop does not help much.

Suggest to use a function to create the label and put it in the canvas.  It will reduce some redundant code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def new_label(canvas, x, y, **kw):
    lbl = tk.Label(canvas, **kw)
    item_id = canvas.create_window(x, y, window=lbl)
    # return the label reference and the item ID in case they are required later
    return lbl, item_id

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

new_label(canvas, 250, 30, text="Welcome", font="Arial 16 bold", width=20, fg="white", bg="blue")
new_label(canvas, 70, 70, text="Type Value 1")
new_label(canvas, 70, 110, text="Type Value 2")
new_label(canvas, 130, 150, text="Choose the number of operation")
new_label(canvas, 70, 175, text="1. Add")
new_label(canvas, 150, 175, text="2. Substract")
new_label(canvas, 255, 175, text="3. Multiplication")
new_label(canvas, 355, 175, text="4. Division")
new_label(canvas, 270, 250, text="Result:")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you so much for your help.
You made my day !

Then, what is the meaning of **kw?

Comment: `**kw` refers to the keyword arguments, like `text=..., font=...`.